# How to know the adress of call in main, and what do this values mean? GDB

Tags: assembly, gdb

so i am doing some basic assembly exercises since i'm not very experienced with it and i can't find an answer to this questions.

First one asks for the address of the call instruction that calls the function "calc" on main. It tells me that "calc" has 5 bytes. I only have the assembly code for the function calc itself. The adress of "calc" is 0x08048424 and the last one is

```
8048470: c3    ret
```

Ret has nothing in front of it. How do i know the address of call based on this or am i missing something?

The second one, i have this line of code in the middle of "calc":

```
804845f: 7e **??**        jle 8048454
```

It asks me to replace the ?? with the right byte value, and justify why. What does those values mean? I can't find that anywhere. And what would be the answer?

Thanks guys

Comment: Your question seems to be unrelated to GDB.

Comment: Really. I won't do the exercise for you but I would try to help you with GDB. But for that I would need a minimal example, some information what you tried and what went wrong. Unless you provide that, you're lucky to get any response at all.

Comment: @user2799037 how can i give you a try? Well i guess that the call function will be next instruction on main less 5 bytes. But how will i know this? The second question i don't know the meaning of the values before the instruction. If you can tell me what they are, i can try and resolve it

Answer (score 0):

The ?? (second byte) represent the relative offset of the JMP instruction.

I found more information here:

http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/2bytejumps.htm

Hope it helps someone